# Как сделать тень (drop-shadow) градиентом

Tags: css, градиент

Есть такой пример.

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  i.style.filter = 'drop-shadow(' + e.clientX / 100 + 'px ' + e.clientY / 100 + 'px 5px rgb(' + e.clientX / 3 + ' ' + e.clientX / 3 + ' ' + e.clientY / 3 + ' ))';
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

div#i {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: drop-shadow(10px 1px 3px red);
  background-image: url('https://precisiongrinding.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/Global-Map.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="i"></div>
```

Как можно реализовать данный пример, чтобы тень картинки была градиентом?

Comment: наверно если карту отрисовать в векторе или в canvas то на каждый шейп можно будет наложить отдельно тень ..как идея ?

Comment: Уже делаю)))))))

Comment: Напишешь о результате..ок?

Comment: @MaximLensky, Max, то что ты предложил,это первое, что пришло в голову...  Просто подумал, может есть вариант проще в `CSS`, может чего не знаю...

Comment: Да нее ...png разве что map на html,css

Comment: кстати если будут проблемы с картой - пиши я скину

Comment: Благодарю, я нашел то, что искал...  Даже лучше желаемого..  Но в любом случае благодарю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  p.style.transform = 'translate(' + e.clientX / 100 + 'px, ' + e.clientY / 100 + 'px) scale(0.1, -0.1)';
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: #272727;
}

g#p {
  fill: url(#gradient);
  stroke: url(#gradient);
  stroke-width: 45px;
}

g#b {
  transform: scale(0.1, -0.1);
  fill: #99999999;
  stroke: transparent;
  stroke-width: 15px;
  stroke: url(#gradient);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20010904//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-SVG-20010904/DTD/svg10.dtd">
<svg version="1.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 -654 1280 654">
        <defs>
            <linearGradient id="gradient" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="0%" y2="100%">
                <stop offset="0%" stop-color="orange" />
                <stop offset="100%" stop-color="red" />
            </linearGradient>
        </defs>
        <g id="p">
            <path d="M3825 6516 c-44 -12 -96 -31 -115 -43 -40 -26 -47 -28 -213 -48 -111 -14 -131 -20 -152 -41 -14 -14 -25 -28 -25 -33 0 -18 48 -49 87 -56 23 -3 59 -15 80 -26 47 -24 64 -24 114 1 30 16 44 18 59 10 15 -8 20 -8 20 3 0 25 46 57 96 66 92 18 245 52 327 71 45 11 85 20 89 20 4 0 6 -13 6 -29 -1 -46 -39 -61 -152 -61 -136 0 -129 -25 14 -50 69 -12 79 -17 137 -68 59 -52 64 -61 88 -138 30 -99 30 -104 4 -138 -19 -25 -27 -27 -78 -25 l-56 3 2 -30 c8 -130 70 -253 150 -297 46 -24 49 -25 69 -9 26 22 73 84 107 144 32 55 44 63 141 89 101 28 126 39 126 58 0 9 14 22 33 29 47 18 270 62 316 62 31 0 49 7 75 30 33 29 35 34 33 93 -2 88 11 107 74 107 51 0 117 22 131 43 4 7 8 26 8 43 0 36 34
71 100 104 25 12 46 24 48 25 2 2 -7 14 -20 28 -26 28 -79 40 -153 36 -27 -1
-183 -3 -345 -3 -256 -1 -299 1 -325 15 -27 15 -37 16 -105 3 -112 -22 -442
-8 -619 26 -68 13 -78 12 -176 -14z" />
            <path d="M9095 6259 c-49 -4 -98 -5 -109 -2 -11 3 -29 -6 -50 -26 -44 -42 -96
-61 -195 -71 -131 -12 -211 -32 -211 -51 0 -8 7 -37 16 -63 14 -40 14 -52 3
-72 -19 -36 -49 -27 -84 26 -16 25 -38 57 -48 70 l-18 25 6 -25 c4 -14 20 -53
36 -86 16 -34 29 -69 29 -78 0 -17 -35 -29 -71 -24 -22 3 -25 9 -30 68 -8 86
-36 134 -93 155 -24 9 -56 15 -72 13 -26 -3 -29 -7 -28 -35 2 -35 66 -123 90
-123 41 0 -7 -46 -58 -55 -49 -9 -167 27 -199 61 -29 31 -57 26 -112 -17 -24
-20 -44 -28 -56 -24 -10 3 -31 1 -46 -5 -20 -8 -31 -7 -41 1 -18 15 -89 15
-107 1 -7 -6 -52 -25 -100 -43 -66 -23 -108 -47 -169 -95 -45 -35 -87 -64 -93
-64 -7 0 -29 15 -50 33 -20 17 -52 44 -69 59 -24 21 -28 29 -19 39 13 13 90
15 141 4 25 -6 38 -3 52 10 39 35 24 53 -65 74 -27 7 -63 19 -80 26 -50 23
-260 55 -374 58 l-108 2 -59 -39 c-73 -49 -202 -145 -271 -203 -36 -30 -53
-52 -53 -68 0 -31 -22 -47 -76 -53 -37 -4 -47 -10 -55 -29 -10 -28 -12 -77 -2
-111 l6 -24 21 26 21 26 80 -41 c96 -50 96 -49 104 -89 4 -23 15 -35 38 -45
31 -13 35 -12 80 18 27 18 55 46 64 64 9 17 24 44 33 58 16 24 16 28 2 44 -19
20 -19 60 -3 115 10 32 23 45 76 77 70 42 92 47 111 24 11 -13 6 -26 -24 -75
-35 -57 -36 -60 -21 -84 22 -33 29 -35 109 -25 48 6 74 5 83 -2 47 -40 -48
-91 -108 -58 -20 10 -20 9 -14 -43 8 -65 -6 -85 -50 -68 -35 13 -45 6 -45 -34
0 -52 -33 -76 -107 -76 -45 0 -67 -5 -86 -20 -32 -25 -38 -25 -71 1 -27 21
-55 22 -143 4 -27 -6 -33 -4 -33 9 0 25 -18 19 -57 -19 -20 -19 -46 -35 -59
-35 -40 0 -74 -21 -74 -46 0 -24 -26 -45 -46 -37 -6 2 -27 -14 -47 -36 -20
-22 -44 -44 -54 -49 -22 -12 -87 -24 -132 -26 -47 -1 -50 -22 -7 -43 20 -9 36
-20 36 -25 0 -4 -26 -8 -57 -8 l-58 -1 25 -20 c74 -60 99 -93 88 -113 -5 -9
-7 -20 -4 -25 11 -16 -5 -40 -37 -56 -38 -19 -60 -19 -98 1 -17 8 -53 19 -80
23 -46 8 -51 6 -73 -19 -20 -24 -24 -43 -30 -145 -9 -149 -5 -157 91 -173 37
-7 80 -15 94 -18 25 -6 40 2 140 69 29 20 37 33 42 66 6 50 19 66 68 91 20 11
47 35 59 55 30 49 50 57 119 49 l60 -6 3 33 c2 25 7 33 18 30 8 -3 26 -5 39
-5 17 -1 31 -12 43 -33 20 -33 66 -65 109 -76 25 -6 149 -112 149 -127 0 -23
-53 -69 -83 -72 l-32 -4 28 -14 c27 -13 29 -12 72 30 32 31 45 52 45 72 0 30
6 33 30 19 8 -6 18 -7 23 -4 14 8 -63 82 -113 108 -56 29 -126 101 -135 138
-14 57 55 29 172 -70 28 -23 59 -43 68 -43 36 0 53 -19 60 -69 4 -28 13 -56
22 -62 8 -7 24 -31 35 -53 33 -65 60 -96 84 -96 16 0 23 8 28 30 3 18 12 30
21 30 22 0 19 13 -10 40 -15 14 -25 35 -25 52 0 31 7 33 43 17 19 -9 30 -7 58
10 59 36 65 31 66 -56 2 -68 5 -79 25 -95 53 -42 83 -53 158 -54 227 -4 219
-3 229 -22 23 -44 -46 -222 -95 -244 -23 -11 -308 2 -394 17 -43 8 -141 54
-157 75 -11 13 -12 11 -13 -13 0 -15 -10 -47 -22 -70 l-23 -42 -55 5 c-33 3
-67 13 -85 26 -60 42 -117 66 -146 60 -22 -4 -32 0 -49 22 -12 14 -35 32 -51
39 -25 10 -29 17 -29 50 0 21 7 51 15 67 33 63 18 72 -82 47 -43 -10 -127 -24
-187 -30 -71 -7 -118 -17 -135 -28 -19 -13 -49 -18 -111 -18 -47 -1 -98 -5
-113 -10 -20 -5 -33 -3 -46 9 -18 16 -20 14 -55 -32 -20 -28 -55 -59 -80 -72
-46 -25 -76 -73 -76 -123 0 -21 -26 -53 -118 -144 -78 -78 -126 -133 -139
-163 -69 -154 -66 -145 -59 -207 12 -96 7 -153 -21 -222 -20 -51 -23 -68 -14
-83 6 -10 11 -37 11 -60 0 -40 4 -46 47 -78 33 -25 59 -58 90 -115 45 -83 134
-179 195 -211 17 -9 57 -19 89 -21 47 -5 66 -1 99 16 24 12 50 19 63 15 21 -5
125 20 189 45 44 17 107 21 159 10 39 -8 55 -19 80 -51 26 -33 37 -39 58 -35
39 8 93 -23 114 -63 20 -40 19 -116 -3 -192 l-14 -47 51 -53 c56 -60 66 -75
89 -144 9 -27 25 -62 37 -78 14 -20 20 -46 22 -95 1 -36 7 -76 13 -88 17 -31
1 -100 -40 -174 -23 -41 -38 -84 -41 -119 -6 -50 -4 -60 23 -100 16 -25 42
-74 56 -110 14 -36 33 -81 41 -100 8 -19 19 -71 24 -115 14 -128 20 -148 55
-187 45 -50 71 -103 79 -163 15 -101 67 -157 116 -126 10 6 39 11 63 11 24 0
66 9 93 21 26 11 56 22 66 24 20 4 197 162 197 176 0 5 13 15 29 23 20 11 40
39 69 99 39 80 102 157 130 157 15 0 17 106 2 115 -30 19 16 128 80 192 23 23
66 59 96 79 46 32 55 44 68 88 18 66 8 186 -28 314 -37 133 -35 158 17 225 23
31 77 102 121 159 43 57 104 128 135 158 31 30 91 105 133 167 65 94 80 124
98 193 12 45 19 84 17 86 -2 3 -25 -2 -51 -11 -27 -9 -74 -15 -109 -14 -34 1
-96 -2 -138 -6 l-76 -7 -13 53 c-14 63 -78 165 -158 254 -32 34 -67 80 -80
102 -23 39 -34 63 -111 247 -23 55 -61 137 -86 183 -51 95 -54 105 -21 74 17
-16 30 -20 49 -16 20 5 31 1 49 -18 51 -54 118 -156 143 -217 33 -80 57 -122
104 -180 66 -81 118 -174 125 -218 16 -110 63 -153 144 -132 26 6 71 27 102
45 30 19 93 50 140 70 93 38 191 116 231 183 12 20 44 60 71 89 26 28 48 56
48 61 0 5 -22 23 -50 40 -54 33 -110 110 -110 149 0 34 -13 29 -57 -21 -27
-30 -57 -51 -93 -65 -58 -22 -60 -22 -116 26 -22 19 -104 232 -104 270 0 34
15 35 39 2 13 -17 56 -52 96 -79 69 -44 79 -48 160 -55 61 -5 88 -11 92 -21 3
-8 25 -28 49 -45 44 -30 48 -30 192 -35 167 -6 204 -17 267 -76 76 -71 100
-95 122 -122 26 -32 61 -34 97 -5 15 12 28 20 29 18 34 -62 37 -78 32 -129 -6
-52 -3 -63 49 -175 31 -66 56 -127 56 -136 0 -8 7 -24 15 -35 8 -10 15 -26 15
-35 0 -19 47 -140 59 -152 13 -13 72 16 105 51 l29 31 -6 114 -7 113 39 81
c37 76 43 83 99 113 36 19 78 53 107 86 26 30 64 66 84 80 34 22 42 23 90 14
80 -15 103 -30 137 -90 39 -68 92 -130 110 -130 19 0 34 -32 34 -72 0 -49 18
-63 46 -37 36 34 56 21 82 -51 18 -50 23 -85 23 -150 -1 -82 12 -150 29 -150
13 0 20 41 20 121 0 60 4 82 19 100 16 20 21 21 35 10 9 -7 16 -18 16 -24 0
-9 25 -37 147 -164 31 -33 33 -34 62 -19 68 35 161 152 161 201 0 33 -103 182
-168 242 l-67 62 18 33 c10 19 35 54 56 78 l37 44 45 -25 44 -24 3 -78 c2 -52
7 -77 14 -75 6 2 30 39 53 82 63 115 89 140 172 165 83 25 130 69 169 158 46
103 21 196 -81 305 -36 38 -73 85 -82 104 -15 30 -15 35 -1 51 22 25 48 79 42
86 -4 3 -16 2 -28 -3 -25 -9 -143 -12 -168 -4 -10 3 -18 12 -18 19 0 21 88
142 120 165 37 27 47 25 54 -7 11 -46 30 -83 42 -83 6 0 23 10 38 21 23 18 32
20 51 11 14 -7 27 -23 31 -39 3 -15 7 -33 9 -40 2 -7 27 -24 55 -38 49 -25 50
-27 50 -69 0 -89 69 -104 128 -27 18 24 32 51 30 60 -2 8 -28 32 -58 53 -109
76 -120 86 -120 122 0 18 9 45 20 59 11 14 20 39 20 56 0 38 22 51 89 51 l50
0 26 57 c22 49 26 74 29 166 3 104 2 109 -20 124 -13 8 -37 37 -55 64 -17 27
-41 55 -53 61 -11 6 -76 14 -144 18 -67 4 -125 10 -129 14 -14 14 -15 121 -2
152 8 17 36 50 62 74 39 36 56 44 85 44 53 -1 199 -24 252 -40 42 -13 46 -12
63 7 9 12 17 36 17 54 0 23 9 43 30 65 l31 33 22 -22 c29 -27 57 -27 91 0 43
33 67 22 84 -38 14 -51 14 -53 -12 -83 -36 -44 -35 -95 3 -147 16 -22 41 -43
55 -47 19 -5 27 -15 31 -40 5 -25 24 -49 77 -95 38 -33 73 -61 77 -61 13 0 20
191 9 237 -12 49 -44 83 -90 92 -27 5 -34 12 -36 34 -2 16 2 35 8 42 13 16
118 75 133 75 6 0 7 -17 3 -40 -6 -40 -6 -41 16 -26 13 8 40 36 61 61 33 39
43 45 76 45 21 0 43 6 49 13 8 9 -12 24 -84 62 -52 27 -94 53 -94 56 0 4 10
11 23 15 12 3 30 15 40 25 20 21 37 19 161 -18 44 -12 91 -23 105 -23 24 0 23
2 -17 40 -53 51 -136 75 -230 67 -51 -5 -73 -2 -115 15 -29 12 -140 36 -247
54 -206 35 -197 35 -225 -11 -9 -15 -17 -14 -95 4 -47 12 -150 26 -230 32
-101 8 -153 17 -170 28 -20 13 -65 17 -235 21 -174 4 -214 8 -235 22 -14 9
-44 21 -67 27 -23 7 -49 18 -58 27 -13 14 -16 13 -24 -9 -14 -35 -81 -87 -113
-87 -15 0 -47 4 -70 10 -24 5 -86 13 -139 18 -65 6 -109 15 -137 30 -58 30
-172 39 -241 18 -75 -22 -156 -20 -211 5 -38 17 -61 20 -145 17 -117 -4 -127
6 -70 65 19 20 35 38 35 40 0 3 -13 10 -30 17 -20 8 -51 10 -93 6 -47 -5 -70
-3 -92 8 -32 17 -34 17 -170 5z" />
            <path d="M2096 6159 c-48 -33 -76 -55 -76 -60 0 -3 11 -6 26 -7 14 -1 34 -6
44 -12 10 -5 35 -10 55 -10 37 0 37 0 31 -34 -6 -29 -3 -37 19 -55 22 -16 38
-19 88 -17 34 2 75 7 90 11 17 4 44 3 65 -4 32 -10 48 -8 115 11 l78 23 4 63
c1 34 -1 62 -6 62 -5 0 -26 -7 -47 -16 -20 -9 -55 -17 -77 -19 -22 -1 -54 -6
-71 -10 -27 -6 -39 0 -95 43 -60 46 -70 50 -133 54 -62 4 -72 1 -110 -23z" />
            <path d="M3205 6127 c-38 -33 -38 -35 -26 -65 21 -51 36 -58 62 -28 25 29 49
32 105 12 22 -7 60 -16 86 -20 46 -7 46 -7 72 -72 40 -100 38 -107 -58 -154
-28 -14 -51 -32 -51 -40 0 -17 119 -84 178 -100 62 -18 101 8 62 40 -18 15
-20 56 -2 63 7 3 24 -1 38 -9 13 -7 27 -13 32 -14 14 0 7 41 -14 82 -20 38
-20 40 -2 35 63 -20 62 -20 68 6 10 38 -10 89 -49 126 -29 28 -33 37 -23 51
16 27 -5 46 -58 53 -25 4 -72 21 -105 38 l-60 31 -82 -17 c-46 -9 -85 -19 -87
-21 -3 -2 -14 5 -26 16 l-21 20 -39 -33z" />
            <path d="M2900 6061 c-16 -4 -34 -24 -50 -52 -32 -58 -65 -99 -96 -120 -24
-15 -29 -15 -87 9 -52 21 -80 26 -180 28 l-118 2 -36 -34 c-32 -30 -38 -33
-52 -20 -9 8 -43 20 -76 27 -74 15 -96 26 -89 43 4 10 -22 14 -118 19 -67 4
-148 12 -180 19 -76 16 -232 -1 -343 -38 -105 -34 -155 -30 -196 17 -16 19
-34 44 -39 57 -9 21 -15 22 -124 22 -62 0 -149 -7 -192 -15 -44 -8 -122 -16
-175 -19 -52 -3 -113 -11 -135 -19 -21 -9 -62 -18 -91 -21 -52 -5 -153 -42
-153 -56 0 -4 7 -13 15 -20 19 -16 19 -44 1 -59 -11 -9 -29 -8 -80 6 -65 17
-66 17 -93 -4 -35 -25 -35 -43 -1 -62 24 -14 28 -14 46 3 12 10 31 16 48 14
l27 -3 -27 -32 c-31 -36 -77 -53 -150 -53 -37 0 -59 -7 -97 -32 -27 -17 -50
-38 -51 -47 -7 -74 -7 -72 43 -94 49 -20 58 -30 39 -42 -17 -11 -11 -28 8 -20
9 4 49 15 87 25 84 22 109 33 154 65 41 30 49 31 53 6 3 -18 7 -18 66 10 71
32 69 32 284 -7 76 -14 99 -22 104 -36 3 -10 11 -18 18 -18 7 0 25 -11 40 -25
24 -22 26 -30 26 -104 0 -44 -5 -92 -10 -107 -8 -20 -6 -50 10 -120 26 -122
26 -132 -5 -140 -18 -4 -28 -17 -36 -44 -6 -20 -33 -66 -60 -101 -27 -35 -65
-89 -85 -119 -20 -30 -50 -69 -66 -87 -30 -31 -30 -31 -25 -130 7 -144 25
-194 91 -242 l53 -39 6 -80 c3 -43 10 -90 15 -103 6 -13 17 -49 26 -79 12 -44
86 -180 86 -159 0 31 -42 194 -58 225 -33 64 -37 106 -13 128 19 17 20 17 45
-21 13 -21 28 -56 32 -78 8 -45 67 -170 95 -200 10 -11 40 -61 67 -110 46 -85
49 -94 44 -148 -4 -53 -3 -57 20 -66 13 -5 45 -25 70 -44 99 -76 237 -128 296
-111 56 15 64 13 117 -27 78 -58 123 -79 175 -79 42 0 48 -4 87 -49 27 -31 46
-65 52 -93 11 -48 70 -108 107 -108 12 0 32 -8 45 -19 27 -20 69 -36 69 -25 0
4 -28 33 -62 64 -60 56 -62 59 -65 116 -3 33 0 94 5 137 8 78 8 79 -16 88 -29
11 -131 14 -161 4 l-21 -6 21 53 c82 205 83 214 37 226 -57 15 -80 2 -111 -62
-22 -47 -35 -60 -70 -76 -67 -30 -168 -5 -215 54 -39 51 -37 96 14 253 38 118
52 147 73 160 14 9 43 27 64 41 34 23 103 47 168 59 20 4 27 0 31 -15 4 -13
17 -21 44 -25 37 -6 41 -4 76 37 l37 43 52 -9 c50 -9 113 -41 135 -69 6 -8 14
-40 17 -71 5 -56 32 -128 47 -128 4 0 20 16 35 36 27 35 28 38 17 103 -24 144
-24 155 7 185 15 15 86 66 157 114 87 59 134 97 143 117 8 17 52 67 98 113 45
46 83 87 83 91 0 16 61 41 99 41 36 0 41 3 41 22 0 31 99 122 152 141 24 8 67
24 97 36 41 17 51 18 42 7 -7 -8 -21 -18 -31 -21 -10 -3 -18 -14 -18 -23 0 -9
-3 -29 -7 -44 -9 -36 2 -35 55 5 24 17 51 38 61 45 9 7 32 15 51 17 50 7 108
36 108 55 0 26 -8 28 -53 12 -50 -18 -137 -10 -137 13 0 8 18 27 40 41 22 15
37 31 34 36 -4 6 -44 7 -105 3 -87 -6 -99 -5 -99 9 0 40 133 75 315 82 117 6
146 10 175 28 52 31 120 96 120 116 0 22 -46 65 -55 51 -11 -19 -24 -12 -41
22 -9 17 -25 39 -36 48 -18 14 -19 21 -9 89 5 41 8 77 5 82 -10 16 -40 8 -104
-27 -36 -19 -73 -35 -82 -35 -22 0 -41 35 -35 65 8 43 -31 75 -113 96 l-75 18
-55 -54 c-43 -42 -60 -53 -77 -49 -19 5 -23 1 -29 -31 -3 -20 -3 -67 0 -105
l7 -69 -28 -7 c-15 -3 -54 -16 -87 -27 -61 -23 -65 -28 -85 -104 -12 -45 -32
-58 -74 -48 -45 12 -60 38 -52 90 3 26 13 49 21 52 30 11 11 20 -83 37 -75 14
-110 26 -149 52 -56 36 -64 49 -64 98 0 27 10 42 49 79 65 61 215 133 312 151
46 8 61 26 68 78 l6 41 31 -26 c31 -26 32 -26 55 -8 38 29 83 50 135 61 58 13
114 53 114 81 0 27 -27 35 -49 15 -16 -15 -142 -65 -163 -66 -5 0 -8 13 -8 28
0 21 -7 32 -26 41 -24 11 -26 15 -20 51 6 37 4 40 -16 39 -13 -1 -34 -4 -48
-8z" />

        </g>
        <g id="b">
            <path d="M3825 6516 c-44 -12 -96 -31 -115 -43 -40 -26 -47 -28 -213 -48 -111 -14 -131 -20 -152 -41 -14 -14 -25 -28 -25 -33 0 -18 48 -49 87 -56 23 -3 59 -15 80 -26 47 -24 64 -24 114 1 30 16 44 18 59 10 15 -8 20 -8 20 3 0 25 46 57 96 66 92 18 245 52 327 71 45 11 85 20 89 20 4 0 6 -13 6 -29 -1 -46 -39 -61 -152 -61 -136 0 -129 -25 14 -50 69 -12 79 -17 137 -68 59 -52 64 -61 88 -138 30 -99 30 -104 4 -138 -19 -25 -27 -27 -78 -25 l-56 3 2 -30 c8 -130 70 -253 150 -297 46 -24 49 -25 69 -9 26 22 73 84 107 144 32 55 44 63 141 89 101 28 126 39 126 58 0 9 14 22 33 29 47 18 270 62 316 62 31 0 49 7 75 30 33 29 35 34 33 93 -2 88 11 107 74 107 51 0 117 22 131 43 4 7 8 26 8 43 0 36 34
71 100 104 25 12 46 24 48 25 2 2 -7 14 -20 28 -26 28 -79 40 -153 36 -27 -1
-183 -3 -345 -3 -256 -1 -299 1 -325 15 -27 15 -37 16 -105 3 -112 -22 -442
-8 -619 26 -68 13 -78 12 -176 -14z" />
            <path d="M9095 6259 c-49 -4 -98 -5 -109 -2 -11 3 -29 -6 -50 -26 -44 -42 -96
-61 -195 -71 -131 -12 -211 -32 -211 -51 0 -8 7 -37 16 -63 14 -40 14 -52 3
-72 -19 -36 -49 -27 -84 26 -16 25 -38 57 -48 70 l-18 25 6 -25 c4 -14 20 -53
36 -86 16 -34 29 -69 29 -78 0 -17 -35 -29 -71 -24 -22 3 -25 9 -30 68 -8 86
-36 134 -93 155 -24 9 -56 15 -72 13 -26 -3 -29 -7 -28 -35 2 -35 66 -123 90
-123 41 0 -7 -46 -58 -55 -49 -9 -167 27 -199 61 -29 31 -57 26 -112 -17 -24
-20 -44 -28 -56 -24 -10 3 -31 1 -46 -5 -20 -8 -31 -7 -41 1 -18 15 -89 15
-107 1 -7 -6 -52 -25 -100 -43 -66 -23 -108 -47 -169 -95 -45 -35 -87 -64 -93
-64 -7 0 -29 15 -50 33 -20 17 -52 44 -69 59 -24 21 -28 29 -19 39 13 13 90
15 141 4 25 -6 38 -3 52 10 39 35 24 53 -65 74 -27 7 -63 19 -80 26 -50 23
-260 55 -374 58 l-108 2 -59 -39 c-73 -49 -202 -145 -271 -203 -36 -30 -53
-52 -53 -68 0 -31 -22 -47 -76 -53 -37 -4 -47 -10 -55 -29 -10 -28 -12 -77 -2
-111 l6 -24 21 26 21 26 80 -41 c96 -50 96 -49 104 -89 4 -23 15 -35 38 -45
31 -13 35 -12 80 18 27 18 55 46 64 64 9 17 24 44 33 58 16 24 16 28 2 44 -19
20 -19 60 -3 115 10 32 23 45 76 77 70 42 92 47 111 24 11 -13 6 -26 -24 -75
-35 -57 -36 -60 -21 -84 22 -33 29 -35 109 -25 48 6 74 5 83 -2 47 -40 -48
-91 -108 -58 -20 10 -20 9 -14 -43 8 -65 -6 -85 -50 -68 -35 13 -45 6 -45 -34
0 -52 -33 -76 -107 -76 -45 0 -67 -5 -86 -20 -32 -25 -38 -25 -71 1 -27 21
-55 22 -143 4 -27 -6 -33 -4 -33 9 0 25 -18 19 -57 -19 -20 -19 -46 -35 -59
-35 -40 0 -74 -21 -74 -46 0 -24 -26 -45 -46 -37 -6 2 -27 -14 -47 -36 -20
-22 -44 -44 -54 -49 -22 -12 -87 -24 -132 -26 -47 -1 -50 -22 -7 -43 20 -9 36
-20 36 -25 0 -4 -26 -8 -57 -8 l-58 -1 25 -20 c74 -60 99 -93 88 -113 -5 -9
-7 -20 -4 -25 11 -16 -5 -40 -37 -56 -38 -19 -60 -19 -98 1 -17 8 -53 19 -80
23 -46 8 -51 6 -73 -19 -20 -24 -24 -43 -30 -145 -9 -149 -5 -157 91 -173 37
-7 80 -15 94 -18 25 -6 40 2 140 69 29 20 37 33 42 66 6 50 19 66 68 91 20 11
47 35 59 55 30 49 50 57 119 49 l60 -6 3 33 c2 25 7 33 18 30 8 -3 26 -5 39
-5 17 -1 31 -12 43 -33 20 -33 66 -65 109 -76 25 -6 149 -112 149 -127 0 -23
-53 -69 -83 -72 l-32 -4 28 -14 c27 -13 29 -12 72 30 32 31 45 52 45 72 0 30
6 33 30 19 8 -6 18 -7 23 -4 14 8 -63 82 -113 108 -56 29 -126 101 -135 138
-14 57 55 29 172 -70 28 -23 59 -43 68 -43 36 0 53 -19 60 -69 4 -28 13 -56
22 -62 8 -7 24 -31 35 -53 33 -65 60 -96 84 -96 16 0 23 8 28 30 3 18 12 30
21 30 22 0 19 13 -10 40 -15 14 -25 35 -25 52 0 31 7 33 43 17 19 -9 30 -7 58
10 59 36 65 31 66 -56 2 -68 5 -79 25 -95 53 -42 83 -53 158 -54 227 -4 219
-3 229 -22 23 -44 -46 -222 -95 -244 -23 -11 -308 2 -394 17 -43 8 -141 54
-157 75 -11 13 -12 11 -13 -13 0 -15 -10 -47 -22 -70 l-23 -42 -55 5 c-33 3
-67 13 -85 26 -60 42 -117 66 -146 60 -22 -4 -32 0 -49 22 -12 14 -35 32 -51
39 -25 10 -29 17 -29 50 0 21 7 51 15 67 33 63 18 72 -82 47 -43 -10 -127 -24
-187 -30 -71 -7 -118 -17 -135 -28 -19 -13 -49 -18 -111 -18 -47 -1 -98 -5
-113 -10 -20 -5 -33 -3 -46 9 -18 16 -20 14 -55 -32 -20 -28 -55 -59 -80 -72
-46 -25 -76 -73 -76 -123 0 -21 -26 -53 -118 -144 -78 -78 -126 -133 -139
-163 -69 -154 -66 -145 -59 -207 12 -96 7 -153 -21 -222 -20 -51 -23 -68 -14
-83 6 -10 11 -37 11 -60 0 -40 4 -46 47 -78 33 -25 59 -58 90 -115 45 -83 134
-179 195 -211 17 -9 57 -19 89 -21 47 -5 66 -1 99 16 24 12 50 19 63 15 21 -5
125 20 189 45 44 17 107 21 159 10 39 -8 55 -19 80 -51 26 -33 37 -39 58 -35
39 8 93 -23 114 -63 20 -40 19 -116 -3 -192 l-14 -47 51 -53 c56 -60 66 -75
89 -144 9 -27 25 -62 37 -78 14 -20 20 -46 22 -95 1 -36 7 -76 13 -88 17 -31
1 -100 -40 -174 -23 -41 -38 -84 -41 -119 -6 -50 -4 -60 23 -100 16 -25 42
-74 56 -110 14 -36 33 -81 41 -100 8 -19 19 -71 24 -115 14 -128 20 -148 55
-187 45 -50 71 -103 79 -163 15 -101 67 -157 116 -126 10 6 39 11 63 11 24 0
66 9 93 21 26 11 56 22 66 24 20 4 197 162 197 176 0 5 13 15 29 23 20 11 40
39 69 99 39 80 102 157 130 157 15 0 17 106 2 115 -30 19 16 128 80 192 23 23
66 59 96 79 46 32 55 44 68 88 18 66 8 186 -28 314 -37 133 -35 158 17 225 23
31 77 102 121 159 43 57 104 128 135 158 31 30 91 105 133 167 65 94 80 124
98 193 12 45 19 84 17 86 -2 3 -25 -2 -51 -11 -27 -9 -74 -15 -109 -14 -34 1
-96 -2 -138 -6 l-76 -7 -13 53 c-14 63 -78 165 -158 254 -32 34 -67 80 -80
102 -23 39 -34 63 -111 247 -23 55 -61 137 -86 183 -51 95 -54 105 -21 74 17
-16 30 -20 49 -16 20 5 31 1 49 -18 51 -54 118 -156 143 -217 33 -80 57 -122
104 -180 66 -81 118 -174 125 -218 16 -110 63 -153 144 -132 26 6 71 27 102
45 30 19 93 50 140 70 93 38 191 116 231 183 12 20 44 60 71 89 26 28 48 56
48 61 0 5 -22 23 -50 40 -54 33 -110 110 -110 149 0 34 -13 29 -57 -21 -27
-30 -57 -51 -93 -65 -58 -22 -60 -22 -116 26 -22 19 -104 232 -104 270 0 34
15 35 39 2 13 -17 56 -52 96 -79 69 -44 79 -48 160 -55 61 -5 88 -11 92 -21 3
-8 25 -28 49 -45 44 -30 48 -30 192 -35 167 -6 204 -17 267 -76 76 -71 100
-95 122 -122 26 -32 61 -34 97 -5 15 12 28 20 29 18 34 -62 37 -78 32 -129 -6
-52 -3 -63 49 -175 31 -66 56 -127 56 -136 0 -8 7 -24 15 -35 8 -10 15 -26 15
-35 0 -19 47 -140 59 -152 13 -13 72 16 105 51 l29 31 -6 114 -7 113 39 81
c37 76 43 83 99 113 36 19 78 53 107 86 26 30 64 66 84 80 34 22 42 23 90 14
80 -15 103 -30 137 -90 39 -68 92 -130 110 -130 19 0 34 -32 34 -72 0 -49 18
-63 46 -37 36 34 56 21 82 -51 18 -50 23 -85 23 -150 -1 -82 12 -150 29 -150
13 0 20 41 20 121 0 60 4 82 19 100 16 20 21 21 35 10 9 -7 16 -18 16 -24 0
-9 25 -37 147 -164 31 -33 33 -34 62 -19 68 35 161 152 161 201 0 33 -103 182
-168 242 l-67 62 18 33 c10 19 35 54 56 78 l37 44 45 -25 44 -24 3 -78 c2 -52
7 -77 14 -75 6 2 30 39 53 82 63 115 89 140 172 165 83 25 130 69 169 158 46
103 21 196 -81 305 -36 38 -73 85 -82 104 -15 30 -15 35 -1 51 22 25 48 79 42
86 -4 3 -16 2 -28 -3 -25 -9 -143 -12 -168 -4 -10 3 -18 12 -18 19 0 21 88
142 120 165 37 27 47 25 54 -7 11 -46 30 -83 42 -83 6 0 23 10 38 21 23 18 32
20 51 11 14 -7 27 -23 31 -39 3 -15 7 -33 9 -40 2 -7 27 -24 55 -38 49 -25 50
-27 50 -69 0 -89 69 -104 128 -27 18 24 32 51 30 60 -2 8 -28 32 -58 53 -109
76 -120 86 -120 122 0 18 9 45 20 59 11 14 20 39 20 56 0 38 22 51 89 51 l50
0 26 57 c22 49 26 74 29 166 3 104 2 109 -20 124 -13 8 -37 37 -55 64 -17 27
-41 55 -53 61 -11 6 -76 14 -144 18 -67 4 -125 10 -129 14 -14 14 -15 121 -2
152 8 17 36 50 62 74 39 36 56 44 85 44 53 -1 199 -24 252 -40 42 -13 46 -12
63 7 9 12 17 36 17 54 0 23 9 43 30 65 l31 33 22 -22 c29 -27 57 -27 91 0 43
33 67 22 84 -38 14 -51 14 -53 -12 -83 -36 -44 -35 -95 3 -147 16 -22 41 -43
55 -47 19 -5 27 -15 31 -40 5 -25 24 -49 77 -95 38 -33 73 -61 77 -61 13 0 20
191 9 237 -12 49 -44 83 -90 92 -27 5 -34 12 -36 34 -2 16 2 35 8 42 13 16
118 75 133 75 6 0 7 -17 3 -40 -6 -40 -6 -41 16 -26 13 8 40 36 61 61 33 39
43 45 76 45 21 0 43 6 49 13 8 9 -12 24 -84 62 -52 27 -94 53 -94 56 0 4 10
11 23 15 12 3 30 15 40 25 20 21 37 19 161 -18 44 -12 91 -23 105 -23 24 0 23
2 -17 40 -53 51 -136 75 -230 67 -51 -5 -73 -2 -115 15 -29 12 -140 36 -247
54 -206 35 -197 35 -225 -11 -9 -15 -17 -14 -95 4 -47 12 -150 26 -230 32
-101 8 -153 17 -170 28 -20 13 -65 17 -235 21 -174 4 -214 8 -235 22 -14 9
-44 21 -67 27 -23 7 -49 18 -58 27 -13 14 -16 13 -24 -9 -14 -35 -81 -87 -113
-87 -15 0 -47 4 -70 10 -24 5 -86 13 -139 18 -65 6 -109 15 -137 30 -58 30
-172 39 -241 18 -75 -22 -156 -20 -211 5 -38 17 -61 20 -145 17 -117 -4 -127
6 -70 65 19 20 35 38 35 40 0 3 -13 10 -30 17 -20 8 -51 10 -93 6 -47 -5 -70
-3 -92 8 -32 17 -34 17 -170 5z" />
            <path d="M2096 6159 c-48 -33 -76 -55 -76 -60 0 -3 11 -6 26 -7 14 -1 34 -6
44 -12 10 -5 35 -10 55 -10 37 0 37 0 31 -34 -6 -29 -3 -37 19 -55 22 -16 38
-19 88 -17 34 2 75 7 90 11 17 4 44 3 65 -4 32 -10 48 -8 115 11 l78 23 4 63
c1 34 -1 62 -6 62 -5 0 -26 -7 -47 -16 -20 -9 -55 -17 -77 -19 -22 -1 -54 -6
-71 -10 -27 -6 -39 0 -95 43 -60 46 -70 50 -133 54 -62 4 -72 1 -110 -23z" />
            <path d="M3205 6127 c-38 -33 -38 -35 -26 -65 21 -51 36 -58 62 -28 25 29 49
32 105 12 22 -7 60 -16 86 -20 46 -7 46 -7 72 -72 40 -100 38 -107 -58 -154
-28 -14 -51 -32 -51 -40 0 -17 119 -84 178 -100 62 -18 101 8 62 40 -18 15
-20 56 -2 63 7 3 24 -1 38 -9 13 -7 27 -13 32 -14 14 0 7 41 -14 82 -20 38
-20 40 -2 35 63 -20 62 -20 68 6 10 38 -10 89 -49 126 -29 28 -33 37 -23 51
16 27 -5 46 -58 53 -25 4 -72 21 -105 38 l-60 31 -82 -17 c-46 -9 -85 -19 -87
-21 -3 -2 -14 5 -26 16 l-21 20 -39 -33z" />
            <path d="M2900 6061 c-16 -4 -34 -24 -50 -52 -32 -58 -65 -99 -96 -120 -24
-15 -29 -15 -87 9 -52 21 -80 26 -180 28 l-118 2 -36 -34 c-32 -30 -38 -33
-52 -20 -9 8 -43 20 -76 27 -74 15 -96 26 -89 43 4 10 -22 14 -118 19 -67 4
-148 12 -180 19 -76 16 -232 -1 -343 -38 -105 -34 -155 -30 -196 17 -16 19
-34 44 -39 57 -9 21 -15 22 -124 22 -62 0 -149 -7 -192 -15 -44 -8 -122 -16
-175 -19 -52 -3 -113 -11 -135 -19 -21 -9 -62 -18 -91 -21 -52 -5 -153 -42
-153 -56 0 -4 7 -13 15 -20 19 -16 19 -44 1 -59 -11 -9 -29 -8 -80 6 -65 17
-66 17 -93 -4 -35 -25 -35 -43 -1 -62 24 -14 28 -14 46 3 12 10 31 16 48 14
l27 -3 -27 -32 c-31 -36 -77 -53 -150 -53 -37 0 -59 -7 -97 -32 -27 -17 -50
-38 -51 -47 -7 -74 -7 -72 43 -94 49 -20 58 -30 39 -42 -17 -11 -11 -28 8 -20
9 4 49 15 87 25 84 22 109 33 154 65 41 30 49 31 53 6 3 -18 7 -18 66 10 71
32 69 32 284 -7 76 -14 99 -22 104 -36 3 -10 11 -18 18 -18 7 0 25 -11 40 -25
24 -22 26 -30 26 -104 0 -44 -5 -92 -10 -107 -8 -20 -6 -50 10 -120 26 -122
26 -132 -5 -140 -18 -4 -28 -17 -36 -44 -6 -20 -33 -66 -60 -101 -27 -35 -65
-89 -85 -119 -20 -30 -50 -69 -66 -87 -30 -31 -30 -31 -25 -130 7 -144 25
-194 91 -242 l53 -39 6 -80 c3 -43 10 -90 15 -103 6 -13 17 -49 26 -79 12 -44
86 -180 86 -159 0 31 -42 194 -58 225 -33 64 -37 106 -13 128 19 17 20 17 45
-21 13 -21 28 -56 32 -78 8 -45 67 -170 95 -200 10 -11 40 -61 67 -110 46 -85
49 -94 44 -148 -4 -53 -3 -57 20 -66 13 -5 45 -25 70 -44 99 -76 237 -128 296
-111 56 15 64 13 117 -27 78 -58 123 -79 175 -79 42 0 48 -4 87 -49 27 -31 46
-65 52 -93 11 -48 70 -108 107 -108 12 0 32 -8 45 -19 27 -20 69 -36 69 -25 0
4 -28 33 -62 64 -60 56 -62 59 -65 116 -3 33 0 94 5 137 8 78 8 79 -16 88 -29
11 -131 14 -161 4 l-21 -6 21 53 c82 205 83 214 37 226 -57 15 -80 2 -111 -62
-22 -47 -35 -60 -70 -76 -67 -30 -168 -5 -215 54 -39 51 -37 96 14 253 38 118
52 147 73 160 14 9 43 27 64 41 34 23 103 47 168 59 20 4 27 0 31 -15 4 -13
17 -21 44 -25 37 -6 41 -4 76 37 l37 43 52 -9 c50 -9 113 -41 135 -69 6 -8 14
-40 17 -71 5 -56 32 -128 47 -128 4 0 20 16 35 36 27 35 28 38 17 103 -24 144
-24 155 7 185 15 15 86 66 157 114 87 59 134 97 143 117 8 17 52 67 98 113 45
46 83 87 83 91 0 16 61 41 99 41 36 0 41 3 41 22 0 31 99 122 152 141 24 8 67
24 97 36 41 17 51 18 42 7 -7 -8 -21 -18 -31 -21 -10 -3 -18 -14 -18 -23 0 -9
-3 -29 -7 -44 -9 -36 2 -35 55 5 24 17 51 38 61 45 9 7 32 15 51 17 50 7 108
36 108 55 0 26 -8 28 -53 12 -50 -18 -137 -10 -137 13 0 8 18 27 40 41 22 15
37 31 34 36 -4 6 -44 7 -105 3 -87 -6 -99 -5 -99 9 0 40 133 75 315 82 117 6
146 10 175 28 52 31 120 96 120 116 0 22 -46 65 -55 51 -11 -19 -24 -12 -41
22 -9 17 -25 39 -36 48 -18 14 -19 21 -9 89 5 41 8 77 5 82 -10 16 -40 8 -104
-27 -36 -19 -73 -35 -82 -35 -22 0 -41 35 -35 65 8 43 -31 75 -113 96 l-75 18
-55 -54 c-43 -42 -60 -53 -77 -49 -19 5 -23 1 -29 -31 -3 -20 -3 -67 0 -105
l7 -69 -28 -7 c-15 -3 -54 -16 -87 -27 -61 -23 -65 -28 -85 -104 -12 -45 -32
-58 -74 -48 -45 12 -60 38 -52 90 3 26 13 49 21 52 30 11 11 20 -83 37 -75 14
-110 26 -149 52 -56 36 -64 49 -64 98 0 27 10 42 49 79 65 61 215 133 312 151
46 8 61 26 68 78 l6 41 31 -26 c31 -26 32 -26 55 -8 38 29 83 50 135 61 58 13
114 53 114 81 0 27 -27 35 -49 15 -16 -15 -142 -65 -163 -66 -5 0 -8 13 -8 28
0 21 -7 32 -26 41 -24 11 -26 15 -20 51 6 37 4 40 -16 39 -13 -1 -34 -4 -48
-8z" />
        </g>
    </svg>
```